# asymptotic conical surface how to explain - terminology

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, terminology

How to easily and concisely say what *asymptotic conical surface*, *imaginary conic section*, and *asymptotic plane* are? How to define these terms, please?

Comment: While there may be a most-common usage in a given field (differential geometry?), a phrase like "asymptotic plane" seems ambiguous in general: is it a plane that a particular surface is asymptotic to, or a surface that is asymptotic to a plane?
Is there a paper, book, and/or sentence where these terms appear that you are interested in?

Comment: Thank you, no I have not found papers or books with this term. In it only in my list of terms, I have to know their meaning.

Comment: a list of terms in what context? For instance, if this is for the class, the title of the class (ideally with a syllabus or recommended/required book) would help a lot. For instance, if a class is called "differential geometry" that could help people tag your question so that the people who know about that field could find this question.

Comment: It is an English lesson focused on mathematical terminology.

Comment: I suspect that all of these terms are uncommon at the undergraduate level. If you are not already at the graduate/research level in a relevant subfield of math, it might not be easy to define these "easily and concisely". And I wonder if someone gave you these terms as a joke/trick. I'm going to tag this with "differential geometry" since it seems these may be used in that field.